# c# call a class function in a form to change to another from

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, datagridview

I create 2 windows form and a class in my c# project and i have two `dataGridView`s - one in form 1 and one form 2 with the same name but different content. I create a class and in that class called `Sqlfunctions` I create a `SqlConnection` and 2 method which called `Refresh1 and` Refresh2`. I can use each  of those method in their respected from by this two line.
in form1

```
Sqlfunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
```

in form 2

```
Sqlfunctions.Refresh2(this.dataGridView1);
```

but i need to call Sqlfunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1) in form 2 to update  dataGridView1 in form 1. how can i call a class method in one form to update another form. or how can i call Sqlfunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1) in form 1 when form 2 was closed.

Here is more information:

i open form 2 with a button in form 1 and i update a dateGridView in form 2. when that happen i want to update dateGridView in form 1 too.  because the dategridview in form 2 and 1 are using same
data base. i can update datagridview in form 1 by calling this class function. Sqlfunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1); but i dont know how to call this class function in form 2 to make change to datagridview in form 1. or even how can i run this method in form 1 when form 2 was closed.both way make datagridview in form 1 to update. please help me. im stuck.

i know how to call a method from form 1 when i am in form 2. but the problem is that my method isnt in fomr 1. its in a class called Sqlfunctions

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to know, 1) How to open Form1 from Form2, if its not opened during Form2_Closing event? 2) How to pass this.dataGridView1 i.e. Form1.dataGridView1 as param to Refresh method from Form2.

Comment: Please add some more code which specify your problem.

Comment: i update my post above. please read it again. i just need to call a class function in from 2 to update a datagridview in form 1. i can call that class in form 1 like this (Sqlfunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);) and it update datagridview. but i dont know how to call it in form 2 to make update to dateridview in form1. cause when datagridview in form 2 become update in want datagridview in form 1 become update too

Comment: As for "how can (/SHOULD) I call a method from one form on another: Give the other form a public function(encapsulation) and then use Control.Invoke (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in that function. Otherwise you might run into errors if you try to manipulate data on a form from a thread that doesn't own said form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i open form 2 with a button in form 1

Set Form1 as the Owner of Form2 when you open it, like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);
```

Now over in Form2, you can cast the Owner() property to the Form1 type and use it:

```
// ... from within Form2 ...
Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
Sqlfunctions.Refresh(f1.dataGridView1);
```

**But** you would need to select dataGridView1 in Form1 and change its Modifiers() property to Public for this to work.

Comment: it worked.thank you. my problem has been solved. thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Glad that helped.  If you're problem is solved, click the check mark next to this answer so others know the question is closed.